# webmail fail to redirect to proper url

Tags: php, variables, url

So, I'll start with the most obvious, the code:

```
$code = '<form action="https://'.$params["serverhostname"].':8083/login/" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="'.$params["username"].'" />
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="'.$params["password"].'" />
<input type="submit" value="Login to Control Panel" />
<input type="button" value="Login to Webmail" onClick="window.open(\'http://'.$serverhostname.'/webmail\')" />
</form>';
```

The problem I'm having, is that the login to webmail redirects to only:

```
webmail/
```

Instead of:

```
hostname/webmail
```

The login to control panel works just fine. It's the login to webmail that I'm having issues with.

Thanks for the help or thanks for the trolling, which ever it turns out to be, thanks :)

Comment: What does `$params["serverhostname"]` contain..? Since that one will control which URL will be used for the form submit action.

Comment: $params["serverhostname"] contains the url in the config, ie yourdomain.tld

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
public function get_form($params){
    $serverhostname = $params["serverhostname"];
    $username = $params["username"];
    $password = $params["password"];
    $webmail_action = "http://".$serverhostname."/webmail/";    
    $code = '<form action="'.$serverhostname.'" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="'.$username.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="'.$password.'" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login to Control Panel" />
    <input type="button" value="Login to Webmail" onClick="window.open('$webmail_action')" />
    </form>';
    return $code;
}
```

I am able to done with this way. This way you can easily use php variable in HTML code.

Thanks.

Comment: This actually inside a function, so at the end, it does return $code;

Comment: I have edited code snippet. Try this one. this one is also working as per your requirement. @BBuchanan

Comment: unfortunately, for some reason, this breaks everything. And I can't find a error in any of the logs. I'll revert back for now. I kept getting error 500 pages